# Why is nullable field required with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm trying to use Alembic's `bulk_insert` in the migration file to get some data to my database for testing purposes. This is my database creation code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from alembic import op

def upgrade():
    test_table = op.create_table(
        "test",
        sa.Column("id", sa.String, nullable=False),
        sa.Column("item_id", sa.String, nullable=True),
        sa.Column("object_id", sa.String, nullable=True),
        sa.Column("article_id", sa.String, nullable=True),
        sa.Column("active", sa.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True),
        sa.Column("name", sa.String, nullable=False),
        sa.Column("created_at", sa.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False),
        sa.Column("updated_at", sa.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False),
        sa.Column("deleted_at", sa.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint("id"),
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint("item_id"),
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint("object_id"),
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint("article_id"),
    )
```

The data can have either `item_id`, `object_id`, `article_id`, or all of them at the same time. If the id exists it is a Foreign Key pointing to another table.

This is how I try to insert some test data to the table. It works fine for the first row, but the next one causes an error e.g.: `A value is required for bind parameter 'item_id', in parameter group 1`, if my first object has `item_id` but no other FK's and the second object has no `item_id`. If the first row has an `article_id` and the second one doesn't, the error is `A value is required for bind parameter 'article_id'...`.

```
op.bulk_insert(
test_table,
[
    {
        "id": "test1",
        "item_id": "item001",
        "active": True,
        "name" : "item 1",
        "created_at": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc),
        "updated_at": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc),
    },

    {
        "id": "test2",
        "article_id": "art001",
        "active": True,
        "name" : "article 1",
        "created_at": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc),
        "updated_at": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc),
    }
],
```

)

I can't figure out why this happens, why I can't insert two rows to the database where I have different FK columns given? What I would like to achieve is all FK fields not present would be `Null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue isn't that they are missing but that the dictionaries have different keys.  Try setting the params that appear sometimes and sometimes not to `None`.  I think the statement is compiled and then re-used over and over again, it is probably based on the first set of values in the list.  So later calls fail when the dictionary differs.  I think this is explained here [executing-multiple-statements](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements)

> When executing multiple sets of parameters, each dictionary must have
> the same set of keys; i.e. you cant have fewer keys in some
> dictionaries than others. This is because the Insert statement is
> compiled against the first dictionary in the list, and it’s assumed
> that all subsequent argument dictionaries are compatible with that
> statement.

## Example

```py
op.bulk_insert(
test_table,
[
    {
        "id": "test1",
        "article_id": None,
        "item_id": "item001",
        "active": True,
        "name" : "item 1",
        "created_at": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc),
        "updated_at": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc),
    },

    {
        "id": "test2",
        "item_id": None,
        "article_id": "art001",
        "active": True,
        "name" : "article 1",
        "created_at": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc),
        "updated_at": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc),
    }
])
```